# duplicate objects in list

Tags: networking, duplicates, nodes, rssi, xbee

Im working on a programming project, I want to store some objects in a list but, but I cant get rid of the duplicates.

This is my object

nd = nodeAddress16=0x10,0x03, nodeAddress64=0x00,0x13,0xa2,0x00,0x40,0x6f,0x8d,0xfc, rssi=-47, nodeIdentifier= 
[0x10,0x03]

The code is inside a thread, so the code is looping.

```
private void handleAtCommandResponse(XBeeResponse response) {
    //TODO Implement your code here, to handle particular AT command responses, if desired.
    System.out.println("NetworkNode: Received AT Response:"+((AtCommandResponse)response).getCommand());

    if (response.getApiId() == ApiId.AT_RESPONSE) {
        NodeDiscover nd = NodeDiscover.parse((AtCommandResponse)response);
        System.out.println("Node discover response is: " + nd);

        nodeDiscoverList.add(nd); //add to list, but gives duplicates of nd.

        //add to list if not already in it
        //if already in list replace that object with the new object
        //duplicate objects are not allowed ==> only one object in the list can contain a specific address.
        // Only addresses are static values, other values may change over time.


        }
    else {
        log.debug("Ignoring unexpected response: " + response); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding the rest of the system to help determine why `handleAtCommandResponse` is being invoked multiple times with the same response, note that you can use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementation like [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of a List to keep from storing duplicate objects. You may need NodeDiscover to implement `hashCode()` if it does not already.

A `Set`does not allow duplicate objects. If you call `put()` with the same object (rather, an object whose `hashCode()` is equal to that of another object in the set) twice, the first instance is replaced by the second.